# Combining and minifying JS and CSS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, minify

I created default ASP.NET MVC 3 web application. Then I added three css and three js files to \Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/StyleSheet1.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/StyleSheet2.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JScript1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JScript2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
```

....

when I run the application, I html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/JScript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
```

Is it possible to have a handler in MVC to change my output html to like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <script src="js.axd=/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js,/Scripts/JScript1.js,/Scripts/JScript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css.axd=/Content/Site.css,/Content/StyleSheet1.css,/Content/StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
```

So the link `js.axd=/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js,/Scripts/JScript1.js,/Scripts/JScript2.js`
will return content of all these js files to the browser, and link `css.axd=/Content/Site.css,/Content/StyleSheet1.css,/Content/StyleSheet2.css` will return content of all css files.

I did something before in ASP.NET by IHttpHandler, but can't figure out how to do that in MVC, since I'm just starter in MVC.

Any help and code samples will appreciate.
Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use bundle and minification nuget package. [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

`At the NuGet console type: "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization"`

Example here:

[Using Web Optimization with MVC 3](http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/using-web-optimization-with-mvc-3.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use [cassette](http://getcassette.net/) in my own projects. Also, this list [here](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/minify) contains top 20 in Nuget.