# how to compress css and js files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project we dont use iis compress , becose we use custom CompressFilterAttribute. For views works correctly.
I need to compress css and js files.
Someone have any ideas?

Comment: Check out [bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: Duplicate of [Combining and minifying JS and CSS in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757173/combining-and-minifying-js-and-css-in-asp-net-mvc), first web search hit on "mvc compress css js". Please show research effort. :-)

Comment: if you to bundling files it dont means that compress this files

Answer (score 5):

The most common approach in ASP.NET MVC is to use content bundling: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx

Also note that in IIS you enable static and dynamic content compression separately. To compress JS and CSS you need to enable just the static compression. You would not use dynamic compression in IIS since you are doing that in code. Although if you would enable it as well, it would still work - IIS would detect when the content is already compressed from the code and not do anything else with it.

Comment: <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false"/> in my web config. but static content compress dont work for me

Comment: do you have the matching IIS module installed?

Answer (score 0):

Boundling is great approach, you can also try tools to minification js, less, css, coffiescript, and images.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a56eddd3-d79b-48ac-8c8f-2db06ade77c3 -> images
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6 -> others